# Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

My query show a error Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'

my query

```
SELECT u.id,u.username ,sum(s.score) AS User_Score 
FROM
 `user` AS u ,
 `team_member` as tm
  LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.user_id=u.id and s.game_id=49 and s.team_id=27)
where tm.user_id=u.id and tm.team_id=27
```

Comment: Do you have "id" column in the user table? Didn't you used user_id or something else?

Comment: Make sure the table `user` contains a field `id`

Comment: Note that without a `GROUP BY` clause, this query is probably not going to give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your query with an proper INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT u.id,u.username ,sum(s.score) AS User_Score 
FROM
 `user` AS u 
INNER JOIN
 `team_member` as tm
tm.user_id=u.id
  LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.user_id=u.id and s.game_id=49 and s.team_id=27)
where  tm.team_id=27
GROUP BY u.id
```

It's a matter of precedence, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements
>   that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.

Because of that you can't use the table with the alias name `u` in the join condition of your LEFT JOIN. That's no problem anymore if you use explicit join syntax.

To get the desired result, you should GROUP BY u.id (MySQL permits the optimization to omit the u.username in the list of GROUP BY columns).

Comment: I suspect that a cross join wasn't actually intended, but rather an inner join between `user, team_member` and the left join to `score`, but a confusing mix of implicit and explicit joins was used instead of two explicit joins.

Comment: Yes I think that somewhere hidden is the inner join condition. It's hard to work out though, but found it ...

Answer (score 1):

Your  `join` is not correct:

```
SELECT u.id,u.username ,sum(s.score) AS User_Score 
FROM
 `user` AS u join  `team_member` as tm on tm.user_id=u.id

  LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.user_id=u.id and s.game_id=49 and s.team_id=27)
where  tm.team_id=27
group by u.id,u.username
```

If you use join, you have to use it for all tables and can not mixed with the where statement.

Comment: (this will still need a GROUP BY to produce a meaningful result)

Answer (score 0):

Try without `user AS u`, just `user u`

```
SELECT u.id,u.username ,sum(s.score) AS User_Score 
FROM
  `user` u ,
  `team_member` tm
LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.user_id = u.id and s.game_id = 49 and s.team_id = 27)
where tm.user_id=u.id and tm.team_id=27
```